# how to create index GCP datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, indexing, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I have created a project in GCP and I am using two datastore in it one is the default one and the second is named "secondary" I want to create index for secondary datastore but I am not able to create index for that one because I didn't find any information regarding nondefault datastore. What I tried is following few commands

```
gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml // This creates index on default datastore

gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml --datastore=secondary // This one gives an error 

gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml --namespace=secondary //This one gives an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/create), it should be

```
gcloud datastore indexes create INDEX_FILE [--database=DATABASE]
```

and so for your case, try

```
gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml --database=secondary
```

**Updates**

Per the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_datastore), you have to use GCloud SDK **459.0.0 or higher** because that is where support for the `--database flag`   became available in beta and GA

> Promoted --database flag of gcloud datastore indexes create command to beta.
> Promoted --database flag of gcloud datastore indexes create command to GA.

Comment: No above command didn't work ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.indexes.create) unrecognized arguments: --database=

Comment: @VarunNaharia - I've updated my answer and added the minimum gcloud version you should be running

Comment: One more problem I am getting is --database flag is not working with cleanup do you know why ?

Comment: @VarunNaharia - That option isn't available in the command - [see doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/cleanup). If you have different index files for the different DB (don't know if this is possible), then you can try supplying the path to the index file for the second DB. If a single index file is used for all DBs, then the ```cleanup``` command will do it for all the DBs available.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml --namespace=your-namespace
```

It will create the index as per the specifications in the index.yaml file for the specified namespace.

The index.yaml file should contain the index definitions for the secondary Cloud Datastore. Make sure the index.yaml file is correctly structured with the appropriate index definitions for the entities in the specified namespace.